# Asp.net/C# : asp:FileUpload control has no PostedFiles on codebehind (button click) although the file is appearing on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access an asp:fileupload from codebehind on a button click. Unfourtionatly the control has no files although the filename appear on page.
[image]

The button is inside an updatepanel ( i don't want it to affect the page ).

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel18" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="saveDraftButton" Text="  حفظ بيانات نموذج الإضافة مؤقتاً " OnClick="saveDraftButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

the fileuploads are outside the update panel

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="form-control" />
```

Could you please help me I'm stuck here for awhile.

Comment: Upload Controls do not work in an UpdatePanel. They always need a full PostBack. Either put them outside the UpdatePanel or assign a PostBack Trigger to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the file uploads and controls are outside of the update panel, then when you click the button, ONLY the UP panel is posted to the server. This is the WHOLE idea of a update panel (it ONLY posts back what's inside of the panel - and leaves the rest of the page behind).
This suggests that you don't grasp how a web page and post-back works. You REALLY need to spend time grasping this concept, else you can't really write any web based software.

Regardless of above?

For an update panel,  You can only EVER use controls and get their values when included in the update panel. Only that part of the page (inside the Update panel) will be posted to the server (kind of the whole idea - you can't touch or use controls outside of the update panel such as text boxes, or in this case the file up-load control).

However, what is worse, is the FileUpLoad control does NOT work inside of a update panel anyway - you need a full page post-back.

there are several solutions, but one such solution would be to adopt a file up load control built around ajax, and thus you can up-load multiple files, and do so without a post-back.

There are "oh so many" to choose from. I been using the AjaxFileUpLoad from the ajax toolkit.

It looks like this:

[image]